# Sub-Application module organization with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the preferred way to organize an Angular app with smaller applications?

I have read many articles that discuss organization topics that deal with a cohesive application but, nothing where the 'Larger application' acts as a shell to the smaller, possibly unrelated, applications.

Specifically where I am struggling is with the creation of angular.module(s).  My first instinct is to do something like

```
var portal = angular.module('Portal', [ 'Admin', 'SubApp1', 'SubApp2']);

/**
 * Each of the sub-applications will have their own controllers, etc
 */
var admin = angular.module('Admin', [] );
var subApp1 = angular.module('SubApp1', []);  
var subApp2 = angular.module('SubApp2', []);
```

Each subApp module would be it's own self contained application.

Is injecting the sub-app modules into the portal module/parent application the 'Angular way'?

Comment: This is a perfectly fine approach.

Answer (score 2):

If your modules are small and not related then better way is to create multiple instances of AngularJS applications and bootrstrap them separately.

The advantages of such approach are:

- performance: separated `$digest` phases for each application
- separated css and minified js files for your applications
- separation of `$rootScopes` and variables
- still you can use your applications as modules with larger application

You can bootstrap each application using manual method:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
<head>
     <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="portlet1">
   Hello {{'World1'}}!
  </div>
  <script src="apps/app1.js"></script>

  <div id="portlet2">
   Hello {{'World2'}}!
  </div>
  <script src="apps/app2.js"></script>

  <script>
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('portlet1'), ['app1']);
      angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('portlet2'), ['app2']);
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```